# I can not get an object to rotate around its local axis whit animation-nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I need some help.
I can not get an object to rotate around its local axis whit animation-nodes..
It uses the global.
Here's how my node setup looks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Record the initials transforms of the object using an ID key, then multiply that transformations by a rotation matrix that hold the rotation data you want.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Hi Omar Ahmad
Thank you for a quick response.
It does not seem to work, almost think it's a bug.
The only axis that is local is X. Y and Z use global.

Can anyone confirm that it's a bug, or do I have something wrong with my blender?

// Patrik

Comment: @PatrikRosengren Can you upload the file that have the issue?

Comment: Here's an link to [blend file](http://www.optimalmedia.se/blender/files/object-rigg-animationnodes.blend).

Comment: @PatrikRosengren You haven't added the initial transforms. In the ID Keys panel in AN panel in the 3D viewport, select the object after rotating it to the desired orientation then press *From Current Transforms*. Make sure to disable *Always* auto execution while doing so. Also, in the *Compose Matrix Node*, you haven't checked *Rot*, make sure to.

Comment: I'm sorry, does not make it work.
I can not find Press From Current Transforms and not Rot checkbox in Compose Matrix Node.

Comment: I find them now, but it does not work anyway.

Comment: I'm running  Blender on Windows, that might be the problem. What OS do you run  Omar Ahmad?

Comment: @PatrikRosengren I am running linux, but this should not matter. Can you view the *Matrix* output of the *ID Key Node* using a *viewer node* and tell me what it looks like, is it zeros except for some ones?

Comment: @ OmarAhmad, I have a test on linux and that is the same problem. almost believe it's a bug in the blender. To solve it, I had to do a regular animation in the timeline. rotated x in the global and then z local but i needed to put rotation order two zxy to get z to rotate corruptly.

But if you can solve it, you may want to put out the blend file. I can not make it work with animation nodes anyway.

Comment: @PatrikRosengren I managed to get it to work just as I described. Can you tell me what the output of the matrix output is? You can view it using a viewer node.

Comment: Yeehaa! This was the answer to my problem! Thanks! - Even though I only needed to know about the Object ID key, Initial Transforms part.